# A Double Sum over $\mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ with Symmetry under $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ (Whittaker-Watson)

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem:** Show that the series

\begin{align}\frac{2}{\pi} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{\nu , \nu ' \in {\mathbb{Z}}^{2} \setminus \left\{\left(0 , 0\right)\right\}} \left\{\frac{z}{(1 - 2 \nu - 2 \nu ' z i) \left(2 \nu + 2 \nu ' z i\right)^2}  + \frac{{z}^{- 1}}{\left(1 - 2 \nu - 2 \nu ' {z}^{- 1}\right) \left(2 \nu + 2 \nu ' {z}^{- 1} i\right)^2}\right\}\end{align}

in which the summation extends over all integral values of $\nu$, $\nu '$, except the combination $\left(\nu = 0 , \nu ' = 0\right)$, converges absolutely for all values of $z$ except purely imaginary values; and that its sum is $+ 1$ or $- 1$, according as the real part of $z$ is positive or negative.

**Attempt:** I began by writing $\eta \left(\nu , \nu '\right) = 2 \nu + 2 \nu ' z i$ s.t. the denominator would then become $\left({\eta}^{2} - {\eta}^{3}\right) \left(\nu , \nu '\right)$. For the first term in the summand, I believe that substituting $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ and swapping $\nu$ and $\nu '$ will leave the equation unchanged, so I tried to simplify the problem by only proving that that first term converged. I went through around 3 pages of attempts, and I ultimately proved that it converges everywhere except the imaginary axis and a region surrounding $r = 2 \sin \left(\theta\right)$ when $z$ is expressed in polar coordinates here.

I assume there is a very elegant symmetry to be exploited in this problem. For the only other problem on a series posed by Weierstrass that I read, he introduced an elegant symmetry that allowed the series to be resolved in 4 operations using the compassion test.